# Concatenate two TypeScript type as one

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to know if there is a way to concatenate two typescript types as one example :

```
type Size = 'xl' | 'xxl' ...;
let textSize: 'text-' & Size;
// So my type is something like : 'text-xl' | 'text-xxl'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).

```
type Size = 'xl' | 'xxl';
type TextSizeType = `text-${Size}`;
```

TS resolves `TextSizeType` to

```
type TextSizeType = "text-xl" | "text-xxl"
```

which sounds like what you want.